# Estimating the speed of a moving sound source, given the time of sound arrival at two sensors

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, physics, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I have a sound source with unknown initial coordinates $\langle x,y,z\rangle$, which emits pulses which are subsequently received by two sensors with *known* coordinates $\langle x_1,y_1,z_1\rangle$/$\langle x_2,y_2,z_2\rangle$. The sound source is moving with an unknown velocity $\langle v_x,v_y,v_z\rangle$.

I wish to determine the magnitude of this velocity (i.e., the speed of the sound source) using only the times at which its pulses arrive at each sensor, and those sensor's coordinates. My data consists of a table containing the arrival time at each sensor for each pulse.

We may assume that the pulses travel unimpeded in a straight line from the source to the sensors.

---

While I'm not sure how to begin, I *do* know that I have insufficient information to determine the coordinates of the source at each pulse (a solution in `3D` requires in principle $3$, but in practice *at least* $4$ receivers). Moreover, I believe that I have insufficient information to determine the full velocity (see, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4290572/772290) recent similar (but distinct) post).

Just intuitively, it seems to me that $2$ receivers should be sufficient to estimate the speed. It isn't clear to me how this can be done mathematically.

Comment: I suspect you don't have enough data. If the source is moving in a plane perpendicular to the line segment joining the sensors, meeting that line segment at its midpoint, the source could be twice as far away moving at twice the speed. This might be a special case, but I don't think so. Whether the pulses arrive instantaneously or delayed by the finite speed of sound in the medium may matter.

Comment: If you know the frequency of the pulses, the speed of sound, and can measure the times between pulses to sufficient accuracy, you can use the Doppler effect to determine how fast they are moving away from or towards the sensors. If the pulses are occurring too fast, the source is approaching the sensor. If they are occurring too slowly, the source is moving away.

Comment: Is it assumed that the transmitter is moving on a straight line or is it executing an arbitrary motion ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have a ping table like this:

sensor1: t11, t12, t13, ...
sensor2: t21, t22, t23, ...

I assume that c (speed of sound) and f0 (frequency of pings) are constant and known.

The time differences between same pings define a succession of planes where the emitter was at the time it emitted the ping.
The Doppler-shift of incoming pings for each sensor give relative velocity components. So you are searching for positions within a given plane which are transfered to positions in the next plane by the given velocity components.